# How to get auto-generated INT IDs on a column in Azure SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: azure-synapse

I know that IDENTITY is not supported in Azure SQL Data Warehouse, but is there another way to automatically assign an INT value to a column on insert in the same manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is begin by getting the Max RowId from the table, then in the select statement from you source use a row_number() statement to generate the row number, then simply add the MaxRowId to the row_number to create sequential series of RowId's,

```
DECLARE @MaxRowId int
SET @MaxRowId = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(RowId),0) FROM dbo.MyTable)


INSERT INTO MyTable (RowId, col1, col2)
SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [col1]) + @MaxRowId RowId
, [col1]
, [col2]
FROM dbo.MySourceTable
```